# numberposts not responding to wp_reset_postdata()

Tags: loop, get-posts, wp-reset-postdata

I am working on a loop where I want the content (from 2 separate categories) to be displayed like this:

1 large format post, 1 random product, 2 small format posts, 1 feature post ...repeat.

In order to achieve this I have written a template for the whole page - with a parent loop (yet to be written), then 4 templates for each nested loop ( - large/random/small/feature). The loop templates are loaded into the parent page using `include(locate_template('looptemplate.php'));` - I need to use this method so I can pass a variable (`$do_not_duplicate`) to each loop.

My problem is that I cannot get `numberposts` to reset after each loop template, so if the large-format template uses the argument `numberposts => 1` then in order to make the small-format template show 2 posts it needs to use `numberposts => 3`. This is fine for the first iteration of the parent loop, but it is not repeatable.

Here is the code for the parent page template (NB I have not yet written the parent loop because I'm still trying to solve this problem with `numberposts`):

`<?php $do_not_duplicate = array(); ?>`

`<div id="primary" class="content-area">`

`<div id="content" class="site-content" role="main">`

`<div class="largenews">`

`<?php include(locate_template('largenews.php')); ?>`

`</div><div class="product">`

`<?php include(locate_template('productflash.php')); ?>`

`</div><div class="smallnews">`

`<?php include(locate_template('smallnews.php')); ?>`

`</div><div class="featurepost">`

`<?php include(locate_template('featurepost.php')); ?>`

`</div>`

`</div><!-- #content -->`

And here is the code for largenews.php. (smallnews.php is very similar but want to show 2 more posts)

```
<?php $args = array( 'numberposts' => 1, 'category' => '35,1052');
    $largepost = get_posts($args);
    foreach( $largepost as $post ) : setup_postdata($post);
        if (in_array($post->ID, $do_not_duplicate)) continue;
        array_push($do_not_duplicate, $post->ID);

//Code to format post

    endforeach;
wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Now I have already tried every combination of `numberposts`, `posts_per_page`, `showposts`, `rewind_posts()`, `wp_reset_postdata`, and `wp_reset_query` that I can imagine, but the `numberposts` from the first loop is still being counted in the `numberposts` of the second loop (and any further iterations that will appear).

I have also tried to use  `$largepost->wp_reset_postdata();` but I get this : "Fatal error: Call to a member function wp_reset_postdata() on a non-object".

Apologies for the length of this question but I hope I have made my problem clear, and included all the relevant info. Apologies to for the wonky code formatting, I couldn't get it to work any other way!

Comment: I think you want to exclude the post IDs from the query via `post__not_in`, not from the loop. or maybe I have no clue what you're trying to do here.

Comment: No, it's not the duplicate posts I can't work out, it's the number of posts which each mini-loop displays. I want the "large post" loop to display one post, and the "small post" loop to display two, but it seems that `'numberposts' => 2` argument in the "small post" loop is still affected by the `'numberposts' => 1` argument of the "large post", in spite of having included `wp_reset_postdata();` at the end of each loop.

Comment: with this line: `if (in_array($post->ID, $do_not_duplicate)) continue;`, you appear to be skipping display of these posts in the loop. So in that case, if you don't exclude duplicate posts from the query, you need to query for more posts than end up being displayed, to get past the posts you're skipping. If you exclude duplicate posts from the query, every post you get back is for display, you would remove the duplicate check there, and just add post IDs to the array you're excluding from the next query.

Comment: Oh I see! I would never have worked that out. I think I'd read somewhere that `if (in_array($post->ID, $do_not_duplicate)) continue;` could mess up the pagination, but I did not understand the significance. So I just removed that line, and inserted `'post__not_in' => $do_not_duplicate` into my query. Thanks a million @Milo .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Milo's answer worked perfectly (see comment above).

`if (in_array($post->ID, $do_not_duplicate)) continue;` meant that duplicate posts were still being counted in the loop, though not being displayed.

To fix, remove this line, and exclude duplicate posts from the query with this argument: 
`'post__not_in' => $do_not_duplicate`.

Thank you @Milo for your swift and succinct response.